# Placing div on image

Tags: html, css

How i can place my `div` with `button`, `form` and other content on an image  like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VF2t.png). I have already placed the text on this image using this code:

```css
.img-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.img-wrap h1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 41.5%;
  bottom: 45%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  height: 20%;
  width: 17%;
  padding: 3% 0px 0px 2.4%;
  font-size: 2.3vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  font-family: Alegreya Sans black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="img-wrap">
      <img src="...\images\main-foto.jpeg" class="img-responsive">
      <h1>Funny Island</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to place my div on the same way, but it doesn't work.

```css
.img-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.img-wrap div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="img-wrap">
      <img src="...\images\main-foto.jpeg" class="img-responsive">
      <h1>Funny Island</h1>
      <div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Your formatting is a bit off. Your image URL is missing a quotation mark and has one too many "directory up" dots. Also, don't forget that images are self closing. 


What you have:
<img src=...\images\main-foto.jpeg" class="img-responsive">

What it should look like: 
<img src="../images/main-foto.jpeg" class="img-responsive" />

Comment: Do you have the link of the site in the picture?

Comment: I have correct url,but it's too long so I cut it for a question. And this site is just a model, so i don't have link

Answer (score 0):

Add the image as a background image on .img-wrap. You can then add the buttons, text etc inside the div.

```css
.img-wrap {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url( 'http://placekitten.com/500/300' );
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;

  padding: 50px;
  color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="img-wrap">
        <h1>Funny Island</h1>
         <div>
            <p>Some text here</p>
            <button>Button here</button>
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this -background-image: url(images/main-foto );-  but picture doesn't appear.

Comment: it needs to be like this - background-image: url( 'images/main-foto.jpg' ). Your missing the file extension & '' marks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative on the`margin-bottom` of the element that you wish to contain the image. This will pull the element containing your form content up and above the element with the image inside it. See below for a demo:

```css
.image-container {
  height: 50vh;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: -200px;
}

.content-container {
  height: 150vh;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container"></div>
<div class="content-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add top or left properties to img-wrap div to position it where you want.

```
.img-wrap div{
  position: absolute;
  width:1000px;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: grey;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
 }
```